# Google calendar creation event with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add an appointment to my Google calendar, I can load the data from the calendar through the listen event, but when I try to create a new data to add to the calendar it gives me an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
    import { Component, NgZone, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarOptions } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import { Prenotazioni2 } from 'src/models/data.models';
import { PrenotazioniService } from 'src/app/services/prenotazioni.service';
import { MbscEventcalendarOptions, MbscDatepickerOptions, MbscPopup, MbscPopupOptions, Notifications, MbscEventcalendarView, MbscCalendarEvent, setOptions } from '@mobiscroll/angular';

setOptions({
  theme: 'ios',
  themeVariant: 'light'
});


// This is for testing purposes. Please use your own API KEY. You can get it from https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js
const API_KEY = 'xxx';

// This is for testing purposes. Please use your own CLIENT ID. You can get it from https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js
const CLIENT_ID = 'xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';

const CALENDAR_ID = 'xxx.xxx@gmail.com';
const DISCOVERY_DOCS = ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest'];
const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
const win: any = window;
const now = new Date();

let calApiLoaded: boolean;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendario-aula-blu',
  templateUrl: './calendario-aula-blu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendario-aula-blu.component.css']
})


export class CalendarioAulaBluComponent implements OnInit {

  public prenotazioni: Prenotazioni2[]


  firstDay: Date = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() - 1, -7);
  lastDay: Date = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 2, 14);
  view = 'month';
  calView: MbscEventcalendarView = {
    calendar: { labels: true }
  };

  calSettings: MbscEventcalendarOptions = {
    onPageLoading: (event: any) => {
      const start = event.month ? event.month : event.firstDay;
      const year = start.getFullYear();
      const month = start.getMonth();

      // Calculate dates
      // (pre-load events for previous and next months as well)
      this.firstDay = new Date(year, month - 1, -7);
      this.lastDay = new Date(year, month + 2, 14);

      this.loadEvents(this.firstDay, this.lastDay);
      this.saveEvent();
    }
  };

  myEvents: MbscCalendarEvent[] = [];

  // Init the Google API client
  initClient = () => {
    win.gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: API_KEY,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      scope: SCOPES
    }).then(() => {
      calApiLoaded = true;
      this.loadEvents(this.firstDay, this.lastDay);
    });
  }

  constructor(private notify: Notifications, private prenotazioniService: PrenotazioniService, public zone: NgZone) { }
  @ViewChild('popup', { static: false })
  popup!: MbscPopup;
  popupEventTitle: string | undefined;
  popupEventDescription = '';
  popupEventAllDay = true;
  popupEventDates: any;
  popupEventStatus = 'busy';
  calendarSelectedDate: any = now;
  switchLabel: any = 'All-day';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEntries();
    // Load the Google API Client
    win.onGoogleLoad = () => {
      win.gapi.load('client', this.initClient);
    };
    this.loadGoogleSDK();
  }



  //Funzione per caricare tutte le prenotazioni dell'aula blu nel calendario
  getEntries() {
    this.prenotazioniService.getData().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.prenotazioni = response;

    })
  }

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  loadGoogleSDK(): void {
    ((d: any, s: any, id: any) => {
      let js: any;
      const fjs: any = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        win.onGoogleLoad();
        return;
      }
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onGoogleLoad';
      js.onload = 'onGoogleLoad';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    })(document, 'script', 'google-jssdk');
  }


  // Load events from Google Calendar between 2 dates
  loadEvents(first: Date, last: Date): void {
    // Only load events if the Google API finished loading
    if (calApiLoaded) {
      win.gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
        calendarId: CALENDAR_ID,
        timeMin: first.toISOString(),
        timeMax: last.toISOString(),
        showDeleted: false,
        singleEvents: true,
        maxResults: 100,
        orderBy: 'startTime'
      }).then((response: any) => {
        let event;
        const events = response.result.items;
        const eventList: MbscCalendarEvent[] = [];
        let end;
        // Process event list
        for (const value of events) {
          event = value;
          end = new Date(event.end.date || event.end.dateTime);

          eventList.push({
            start: new Date(event.start.date || event.start.dateTime),
            end: event.end.date ? new Date(end.getFullYear(), end.getMonth(), end.getDate() - 1) : end,
            title: event.summary || 'No Title',
            allDay: !event.start.dateTime
          });
        }
        this.zone.run(() => {
          // Pass the processed events to the calendar
          this.myEvents = eventList;
        });
      });
    }
  }

  changeView(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      switch (this.view) {
        case 'month':
          this.calView = {
            calendar: { labels: true },
          };
          break;
        case 'week':
          this.calView = {
            schedule: { type: 'week' }
          };
          break;
        case 'day':
          this.calView = {
            schedule: { type: 'day' }
          };
          break;
        case 'agenda':
          this.calView = {
            calendar: { type: 'week' },
            agenda: { type: 'week' }
          };
          break;
      }
    });
  }


  tempEvent!: MbscCalendarEvent;
  calendarOptions: MbscEventcalendarOptions = {
    clickToCreate: 'double',
    dragToCreate: true,
    dragToMove: true,
    dragToResize: true,
    view: {
      calendar: { type: 'month', labels: true }
    },
    onEventClick: (args) => {
      this.isEdit = true;
      this.tempEvent = args.event;
      // fill popup form with event data
      this.loadPopupForm(args.event);
      // set popup options
      this.popupHeaderText = 'Edit event';
      this.popupButtons = this.popupEditButtons;
      this.popupAnchor = args.domEvent.currentTarget;
      // open the popup
      this.popup.open();
    },
    onEventCreated: (args) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isEdit = false;
        this.tempEvent = args.event;
        // fill popup form with event data
        this.loadPopupForm(args.event);
        // set popup options
        this.popupHeaderText = 'New Event';
        this.popupButtons = this.popupAddButtons;
        this.popupAnchor = args.target;
        // open the popup
        this.popup.open();
      });
    },
    onEventDeleted: (args) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.deleteEvent(args.event);
      });
    },
    onEventUpdated: (args) => {
      // here you can update the event in your storage as well, after drag & drop or resize
      // ...
    }
  };
  popupHeaderText!: string;
  popupAnchor: HTMLElement | undefined;
  popupAddButtons = ['cancel', {
    handler: () => {
      this.saveEvent();
    },
    keyCode: 'enter',
    text: 'Add',
    cssClass: 'mbsc-popup-button-primary'
  }];
  popupEditButtons = ['cancel', {
    handler: () => {
      this.saveEvent();
    },
    keyCode: 'enter',
    text: 'Save',
    cssClass: 'mbsc-popup-button-primary'
  }];
  popupButtons: any = [];
  popupOptions: MbscPopupOptions = {
    display: 'bottom',
    contentPadding: false,
    fullScreen: true,
    onClose: () => {
      if (!this.isEdit) {
        // refresh the list, if add popup was canceled, to remove the temporary event
        this.myEvents = [...this.myEvents];
      }
    },
    responsive: {
      medium: {
        display: 'anchored',
        width: 400,
        fullScreen: false,
        touchUi: false
      }
    }
  };
  datePickerControls = ['date'];
  datePickerResponsive: any = {
    medium: {
      controls: ['calendar'],
      touchUi: false
    }
  };
  datetimePickerControls = ['datetime'];
  datetimePickerResponsive = {
    medium: {
      controls: ['calendar', 'time'],
      touchUi: false
    }
  };
  datePickerOptions: MbscDatepickerOptions = {
    select: 'range',
    showRangeLabels: false,
    touchUi: true
  };
  isEdit = false;
  loadPopupForm(event: MbscCalendarEvent): void {
    this.popupEventTitle = event.title;
    this.popupEventDescription = event.description;
    this.popupEventDates = [event.start, event.end];
    this.popupEventAllDay = event.allDay || false;
    this.popupEventStatus = event.status || 'busy';
  }
  saveEvent(): void {
    this.tempEvent.title = this.popupEventTitle;
    this.tempEvent.description = this.popupEventDescription;
    this.tempEvent.start = this.popupEventDates[0];
    this.tempEvent.end = this.popupEventDates[1];
    this.tempEvent.allDay = this.popupEventAllDay;
    this.tempEvent.status = this.popupEventStatus;
    if (this.isEdit) {
        // update the event in the list
        var request = win.gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
          'calendarId': CALENDAR_ID,
          'resource': this.tempEvent
        });
        this.myEvents = [...this.myEvents];

    } else {
        this.myEvents = [...this.myEvents, this.tempEvent];
    }
    // navigate the calendar
    this.calendarSelectedDate = this.popupEventDates[0];
    // close the popup
    this.popup.close();
}
  deleteEvent(event: MbscCalendarEvent): void {
    this.myEvents = this.myEvents.filter(item => item.id !== event.id);
    this.notify.snackbar({
      button: {
        action: () => {
          this.myEvents = [...this.myEvents, event];
        },
        text: 'Undo'
      },
      message: 'Event deleted'
    });
    // here you can delete the event from your storage as well
    // ...
  }
  onDeleteClick(): void {
    this.deleteEvent(this.tempEvent);
    this.popup.close();
  }
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't make me create the event in the google calendar

Comment: *it gives me an error* what error?

Comment: in truth it doesn't give me any mistake. it does not add the new event